# Locate an HTML element searching by Title (selenium c#)

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

*How to locate an element by using search by title method, if that is the best way of searching for it in this specific case shown bellow?*

**HTML CODE:**

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#login-window" class="login-window" data-placement="bottom" data-delay="500" title="" data-original-title="Launch the login window">
                        <div class="arrow-down"></div>
                        Login
                    </a>
```

*I am trying to locate the element from above but there is also another element with almost the same properties apart from the Title. What is the best way of locating this element?*

Comment: you can choose the xpath from its parent tag.

Comment: @SarithaG Would you give me an example ?

Comment: This 'a' tag contains some parent tags like <div> or <h> something like that.

Comment: @Mystia We have less information than you to tell you the most appropriate selector. You need to analyze the HTML source yourself, decide what selector (in plain English maybe) would uniquely identify the target element, then we maybe able to help with the XPath implementation

Comment: @har07 Okay can you give me an code example for (in parent list which contains id 'userMenu' find anchor that contains partial href login-window)?

Comment: @Mystia English is good in one way, but also ambiguous in other way. If you can post relevant markup that involved in your selector sentence, that would clarify things well. For now, I guess something like this : `//*[contains(@id, 'userMenu')]/a[contains(@href, 'login-window')]` ?

Comment: @har07 Yes that is it. Can you explain me what is the meaning of (*) after (//) ?

Comment: * means that can be any tag of html.

Comment: @SarithaG Right, but can I put some certain tag instead of * like <li>?

Comment: if <li> contains id='userMenu', you can use li instead of *.

Comment: @Mystia I wasn't sure initially what element you mean exactly by 'parent list' so I used wildcard (`*`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Okay can you give me an code example for (in parent list which contains id 'userMenu' find anchor that contains partial href login-window)?"

according to your comments, by 'parent list' you meant `<li>` and by 'anchor' you meant `<a>`, so this is the xpath for that :

```
//li[contains(@id, 'userMenu')]/a[contains(@href, 'login-window')]
```